# C# How to speed up for loop with large data iteration

Tags: c#

I am iterating in 2509693 data in for loop which is taking long time. i am using VS2013 and .Net v4.5.2

so see my code and suggest some approach or changes for my existing code which speed up execution of my for loop.

This **ds.Tables[1] has 2509693 data** please guide me how to restructure & speed up below code. Thanks

```
public static List<ElementHierarchy> GetElementHierarchy(DataSet ds)
 {
     List<ElementHierarchy> _ElmHierarchy = new List<ElementHierarchy>();
    
     string StrPrevDisplayInCSM = "", DisplayInCSM = "", Section = "", LineItem = "", LastGroupName = "", BGColor="",
         BlueMatrix1stElementFormulaText = "", Type = "", Period = "", EarningsType = "", ParentGroup = "", HeadingSubheading = "", Box="";
     int row = 6, EarningID = 0, LineItemID = 0, BMID = 0, ID = 0, ParentID=0;
     bool IsNextElementGroup = false;
     List<ListOfSection> lstData = new List<ListOfSection>();
     bool IsGreenHeader = false;
    
     for (int p = 0; p <= ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count - 1; p++)
     {
         ID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["ID"].ToString());
         ParentID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["ParentID"].ToString());
            
         EarningID = 0; 
         Section = (ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["Section"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["Section"].ToString());
         LineItem = (ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["LineItem"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["LineItem"].ToString());
         DisplayInCSM = ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["DisplayInCSM"].ToString();
         Type = ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["Type"].ToString();
         BlueMatrix1stElementFormulaText = (ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["BlueMatrix1stElementFormulaText"] == null 
             ? "" : ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["BlueMatrix1stElementFormulaText"].ToString());
         Period = (ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["Period"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["Period"].ToString());
         HeadingSubheading = (ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["HeadingSubheading"] == null ? "" : ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["HeadingSubheading"].ToString());
         Box = (ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["Box"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["Box"].ToString());
         LineItemID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["LineItemID"].ToString());
         BMID = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["BMID"].ToString());
         BGColor = (ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["BGColor"] == null ? "" : ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["BGColor"].ToString());
    
    
         if (BGColor.Contains("ff003300"))
         {
             IsGreenHeader = true;
         }
         else
         {
             IsGreenHeader = false;
         }
    
         if (StrPrevDisplayInCSM != "" && StrPrevDisplayInCSM != DisplayInCSM && (Type == "LINEITEM" || Type=="BM"))
         {
             row++;
         }
    
         if (Type == "GROUP")
         {
             if (IsNextElementGroup)
             {
                 row++;
             }
             else if (p > 0 && !IsNextElementGroup)
             {
                 row++;
    
                 if (p > 0 && HeadingSubheading=="H")
                 {
                     row++;
                 }
    
                 if (p > 0 && HeadingSubheading == "S")
                 {
                     row++;
                 }
             }
             else if (p > 0 && IsGreenHeader)
             {
                 row++;
             }
             else if (p > 0 && ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Any(a => a.Field<int>("ParentID") == ID && a.Field<string>("Type") == "GROUP"))
             {
                 row++;
             }
    
             ParentGroup = DisplayInCSM;
    
             if (HeadingSubheading != "")
             {
                 if (HeadingSubheading == "H")
                 {
                     if (Box != "Y")
                     {
    
                     }
                 }
             }
    
             if(IsGreenHeader)
             {
                 row++;
             }
             else if (ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Any(a => a.Field<int>("ParentID") == ID && a.Field<string>("Type")=="GROUP"))
             {
                 row++;
             }
             IsNextElementGroup = true;
    
         }
         else if (Type == "LINEITEM")
         {
             if (!lstData.Any(a =>
                 a.Section == Section
                 && a.LineItem == LineItem
                 && a.Parent == ParentGroup
                 && a.DisplayINCSM == DisplayInCSM
                 && a.EarningsID == EarningID
                 && a.EarningsType == EarningsType
                 && a.Period == Period
                 ))
             {
    
                 if (!_ElmHierarchy.Any(z => z.RowIndex == row))
                 {
                     _ElmHierarchy.Add(new ElementHierarchy
                     {
                         ID=ID,
                         ParentID=ParentID,
                         RowIndex = row,
                         Section = Section,
                         Lineitem = LineItem,
                         Type = "LI",
                         DisplayInCSM = DisplayInCSM,
                         BMFormula = "",
                         LineitemID = LineItemID,
                         BMID = 0
                     });
                 }
    
                 lstData.Add(new ListOfSection
                 {
                     Section = Section,
                     LineItem = LineItem,
                     DisplayINCSM = DisplayInCSM,
                     Parent = ParentGroup,
                     EarningsID = EarningID,
                     EarningsType = EarningsType,
                     Period = Period
                 });
             }
             IsNextElementGroup = false;
             IsGreenHeader = false;
         }
         else if (Type == "BM")
         {
             IsNextElementGroup = false;
             IsGreenHeader = false;
    
             if (!lstData.Any(a =>
                 a.Section == Section
                 && a.LineItem == LineItem
                 && a.Parent == ParentGroup
                 && a.DisplayINCSM == DisplayInCSM
                 && a.EarningsID == EarningID
                 && a.EarningsType == EarningsType
                 && a.Period == Period
                 ))
             {
                 if (!_ElmHierarchy.Any(z => z.RowIndex == row))
                 {
                     _ElmHierarchy.Add(new ElementHierarchy
                     {
                         ID = ID,
                         ParentID = ParentID,
                         RowIndex = row,
                         Section = Section,
                         Lineitem = LineItem,
                         Type = "BM",
                         DisplayInCSM = DisplayInCSM,
                         BMFormula = BlueMatrix1stElementFormulaText,
                         LineitemID = 0,
                         BMID = BMID
                     });
                 }
    
                 lstData.Add(new ListOfSection
                 {
                     Section = Section,
                     LineItem = LineItem,
                     DisplayINCSM = DisplayInCSM,
                     Parent = ParentGroup,
                     EarningsID = EarningID,
                     EarningsType = EarningsType,
                     Period = Period
                 });
             }
         }
    
         StrPrevDisplayInCSM = DisplayInCSM;
     }
     return _ElmHierarchy;
 }
    
    
 public class ListOfSection
 {
     public string Parent { get; set; }
     public int EarningsID { get; set; }
     public string EarningsType { get; set; }
     public string Section { get; set; }
     public string LineItem { get; set; }
     public string DisplayINCSM { get; set; }
     public string Period { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: The ANY statements are what is causing code to run slow.  So using a Dictionary or Hash would speed up the searching.

Comment: @jdweng Sir can you please share some restructured code which speed up things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things that you could try out:

1. Instead of using `ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]` every time, just get the row at the beginning of the loop and use it. I'm not sure right now if the compiler will do the same internally, but it will be more readable any way:

```cs
    var Row_p = ds.Tables[1].Rows[p];
   ID = Convert.ToInt32(Row_p["ID"].ToString());
    //[...]
```

2. Maybe you can replace the string indexing `ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]["ID"]` by the actual index by deducing it from the first row before the iteration:

```cs
   int IdInd = myMethodToGetIndex(ds.Tables[1].Rows[p], "ID"); 
   // Get here the rest of the IDs (ParentID, Section,LineItem,etc.)
    for (int p = 0; p <= ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count - 1; p++)
     {
          var Row_p = ds.Tables[1].Rows[p];
         ID = Convert.ToInt32(Row_p[IdInd ].ToString());
         //[...]
```

3. Avoid extra convertions. If you know that ID is a numeric value, maybe just call `ID = Convert.ToInt32(Row_p["ID"]);`
4. if BGColor cannot be longer than 8 hex values, maybe `if (BGColor.Equals("ff003300"))` is faster
5. take all repeated operations out of the loop so they are calculated only once. For instance, maybe if the number of GROUPS are relatively small, you can get the list of parentIDs for all GROUPS and then just call `myGroupsParentIDList.Contains(ID)` instead of `ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Any(a => a.Field<int>("ParentID") == ID && a.Field<string>("Type") == "GROUP")`
6. `for (int p = 0; p < ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count; p++)` might be faster although I think it will be peanuts as what it is really increasing processing time is the calls like `if (!lstData.Any(a => ...))` for each row.
7. I'm not sure if this will work for you, but you could try to create a simple ID for your items, and store them in a dictionary instead of  just a list. Something like:

```cs
  Dictionary<string,ListOfSection> dictData = new Dictionary<string,ListOfSection>();
  Dictionary<int,ElementHierarchy> _ElmHierarchyDict = new Dictionary<int,ElementHierarchy>();

  //Entering your for loop

  //[...]

   else if (Type == "LINEITEM")
   {
      // A silly example of a unique DataId
        string DataId =   Section+ LineItem+ParentGroup+ DisplayInCSM+ EarningID+
                         EarningsType+ Period;

       try //you can check dictData.ContainsKey(DataId) but exceptions will be faster, I think
       {
         dictData.Add(DataId,new ListOfSection {...});

         try{  _ElmHierarchyDict.Add(row, new ElementHierarchy{...}); }
         catch{}     
         
       }
       catch{}
        IsNextElementGroup = false;
        IsGreenHeader = false;
   }

   //[...]

   // for loop is done

    lstData = dictData.Values.ToList();
    _ElmHierarchy = _ElmHierarchyDict.Values.ToList();
```

Comment: Many thanks for point wise guide line. for point 5 & 6 not very clear. 5) i am not only querying ParentID but also check Type is GROUP.so if i store only parentID then how could i check Type is Group or not?
6) i have to check for each row `if (!lstData.Any(a => ...)) for each row.` how to restructure this one ?

Comment: Regarding point **5)** , the [solution by Olivier Jacot-Descombes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67317812/10109389) is an efficient approach. About **6)**, I was just pointing out the `-1` in your loop boundary conditions; I know you have to check all rows, thats why I'm suggesting point **7)**

Answer (score 2):

Create SQL procedure , I think ADO.NET will be more speed than your loop

Answer (score 1):

- Every time you do `ds.Tables[1].Rows[p]` is 3 unnecessary property accesses; store the current row once, and access that
- Every time you do .ToString() is an unnecessary method invocation where the value is already a string
- `ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Any` scans **the entire table** for each index. This is effectively a self-join, and C# can't possibly be any faster than SQL for implementing this, since C# doesn't have any way of indexing whereas SQL might.
- ```
           if (HeadingSubheading != "")
         {
             if (HeadingSubheading == "H")
             {
                 if (Box != "Y")
                 {

                 }
             }
         }
  ```

...does nothing. Remove it.

Comment: you said `ds.Tables[1].Rows[p] is 3` this is not clear what are you saying ? please be more elaborate.

Comment: 3 unnecessary property accesses. You don't need to repeatedly access `ds.Tables`, then `Tables[1]`, then `Table[1].Rows`, then `Rows[p]` this many times - it's actually 4 unnecessary accesses, I miscounted - when doing it once per iteration and storing in a variable would work absolutely fine.

Comment: Sir as you said `3 unnecessary property accesses` where is 3 in my code ?

Comment: I literally just told you.

Answer (score 1):

Before the loop store the IDs in a HashSet:

```
var idSet = new HashSet<int>(ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
    .Select(a => a.Field<int>("ParentID"));
```

In the loop you can then test

```
if (p > 0 && idSet.Contains(ID) && a.Field<string>("Type") == "GROUP")) ...
```

This is because a `HashSet<T>` does not have to iterate the set to determine the existence of an ID. `HashSet<T>` and `Dictionary<K,V>` both have a constant access time, not depending on the number of items they contain. I.e., no matter whether they contain 10 items or one million items, you can look up an item by key with the same fast speed.

On the other hand `Any()` has to loop through through half of the rows in average. If you call `Any()` for every row, this gives you 2,509,693 * 2,509,693 / 2 = ~ 3,149,000,000,000 row accesses (in words 3.149 trillions)!

---

I have not studied your logic in detail, but it will speed up things, if you perform as much filtering as possible in a SQL WHERE clause, to reduce the number of rows you are loading from the DB.

Comment: if i store the ParentID in HashSet then does it speed up the things? how it will matter if i store parent id in HashSet ?

Comment: Hashset has O(1), i.e., a constant access time. Any() has O(n) access time.

Comment: Sir please see other lines of code and suggest how to restructure which speed up things. thanks

Comment: as you said `Hashset has O(1), i.e., a constant access time. Any()` if i store ID in Hashset  then also i need to check Type is GROUP or not so i need to query datatable then what would be the point to store only ParentID in Hashset  ?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, this a very nice solution. I would suggest that as Mist is only searching for the ParentIDs in the Fields of type "GROUP", this could be included in the first search to reduce this idSet